# Wp Nav menu walker render custom structure

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wp-nav-walker

I have been trying to get this structure for my menu:

```
<nav>
    <div class="main-nav">
        <div class="dropdown exploreus">
            <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Main Item</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <div class="illustration">
                    <img src="images/explore.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <a href="#">Sub 1</a>
                <a href="#">Sub 2</a>
                <a href="#">Sub 3</a>
                <a href="#">Sub 4</a>
                <a href="#" class="parent-link">Sub 5</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content-2">
                        <a href="#">Sub Sub 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Sub Sub 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Sub Sub 3</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried with nav menu walker, but its not working for me. I tried editing this: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php

No luck any suggestions